# 2nd order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have to solve the following ODE
$$
  \frac{y''}{y'^2} + y'e^y = 0
$$
by finding a function $F(y',y)$ such that its derivative is equal to $\frac{y''}{y'^2} + y'e^y$, then using initial conditions $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$.

---

What I have done so far is this. Using the multivariable chain rule we can deduce the following:
$$
  \frac{d}{dx} \left(F(y',y)\right) = \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx} y'(x)}_{=y''} \cdot \frac{\partial F(y',y)}{\partial y'} + \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx} y(x)}_{=y'} \cdot \frac{\partial F(y',y)}{\partial y}
$$
So by simple comparison we need that $\frac{\partial F(y',y)}{\partial y'} = \frac{1}{y'^2}$ and $\frac{\partial F(y',y)}{\partial y} = e^y$.

Then by integrating both of these equations with respect to either variable $y'$ and $y$ we get
$$
\begin{align*}
  &F(y',y) = \int e^y \, dy = e^y + c(y') \\
  &F(y',y) = \int \frac{1}{y'^2} \, dy' = -\frac{1}{y'} + c(y)
\end{align*}
$$
Thus an appropriate function would be $F(y',y) = e^y - \frac{1}{y'} + C$.
So we have the relationship
$$
  \frac{d}{dx} \left(e^y - \frac{1}{y'} + c\right) = 0
$$
Integrating both sides yields
$$
  e^y - \frac{1}{y'} + c_1 = c_2
$$
Now if $c_1$ and $c_2$ were zero (or identical), this would be easy to solve using separation but as this is nonlinear and inhomogeneous, I have no idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing from your last line we've gotten to
$$\frac{1}{y'}=e^y+c_1$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{e^y +c_1}$$
$$\int\mathrm{d}x=\int e^y+c_1 ~\mathrm{d}y$$
$$x=e^y+c_1y+c_2$$
This is an implicit solution. Unfortunately I don't think there is a closed form for $y(x)$.

We can apply initial conditions as follows: We know that $y=0$ when $x=0$ meaning
$$0=e^0+c_1\cdot 0+c_2\implies 0=1+c_2\implies c_2=-1$$
So our equation is $x=e^y +c_1 y-1$. Taking derivatives,
$$\mathrm{D}_x\{x\}=\mathrm{D}_x\{e^y+c_1y-1\}$$
$$1=y' e^y+c_1y'$$
We are told $y'(0)=1$. So,
$$1=y'(0)e^{y(0)}+c_1 y'(0)$$
But we know $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$.
$$1=1\cdot e^0+c_1\cdot 1\implies c_1=0$$
So our solution considering ICs is
$$x=e^y-1\implies e^y=x+1\implies y=\log(x+1)$$

Comment: How would I apply the initial conditions in that case?

Comment: @millionmilesaway See edit.

Comment: You're awesome! :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{y''}{y'^2} + y'e^y = 0$$
You can integrate directly:
$$-\left( \dfrac 1 {y'} \right)'+(e^y)'=0$$
$$-\dfrac 1 {y'}+e^y=C_1$$
$$-1+y'e^y=C_1y'$$
$$-x+e^y=C_1y+C_2$$